# Adding days to datetime column in df.query() method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.

| Id | arr_date | dep_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-20 | 2022-03-01 |

I want to do the comparison like,
`arr_date` <= `dep_date` + days(7).

How can I do this comparison using df.query() method in pandas? Can anyone please help me?

PS: I know how to do the comparison without df.query(). I only want to know how to do it with df.query()

Answer (score 4):

You can do it all in `query` and without extra imports like so:

```
>>> df.query('arr_date <= dep_date.add(@pd.to_timedelta("7d"))')
   Id   arr_date   dep_date
0   1 2022-01-12 2022-02-01
1   2 2022-01-20 2022-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```py
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Test data 
raw_data = {
    "arr_date" : [date(2022, 1, 12), date(2022, 1, 20), date(2022, 5, 2)],
    "dep_date" : [date(2022, 2, 1) , date(2022, 3, 1) , date(2022, 3, 1)],
    }


df = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_data)
#print(df.info())
print("org-data:")
print(df)

df2 = df[ df["arr_date"]<=df["dep_date"]+timedelta(days=7) ]
print("filtering-data:")
print(df2)
```

output

```bash
org-data:
    arr_date    dep_date
0   2022-01-12  2022-02-01
1   2022-01-20  2022-03-01
2   2022-05-02  2022-03-01


filtering-data:
     arr_date    dep_date
0  2022-01-12  2022-02-01
1  2022-01-20  2022-03-01
```

---

Adds the date of use of the 'timedelta' class.

**df2 = df[ df["arr_date"]<=df["dep_date"]+timedelta(days=7) ]**

[blog](https://dadev.tistory.com/entry/pandas-Adding-days-to-datetime-dataframe-column)

Comment: Please lookup Stack Overflow’s rules about self-promotion when linking to your own content.